# How to save sharedpreference variable outside of ondatachanged?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, sharedpreferences

I am trying to get user details from firebase once login task successful. like username, userphone number etc. so these details I want to store in sharedpreference variable. so that I can use these variables throughout the app. but when I try to save and access from outside its throwing null.

```
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();

                        user_tbl.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                User user1=null;
                                //Check if user not exist in database
                                if (dataSnapshot.child(user.getUid()).exists()) {

                                     user1 = dataSnapshot.child(user.getUid()).getValue(User.class);

                                 //   user_tbl.removeEventListener(this);
                                }
                                editor.putString("username", user1.getUserName());
                                editor.apply();




                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            }
                        });


                        editor.putString("logged", "logged");
                        editor.putString("email",email);

                        editor.commit();
```

Comment: Did you debug to check whether `user1.getUserName()` return any value?

Comment: yes inside onDataChanged its returning correct username. but when i try to access from outside method or from other activity its throwing null

Comment: Querying to firebase is asynchronous operation, so you have to wail till finish the operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Querying to `firebase` is *asynchronous* operation, so you have to wail till finish the operation to get correct data. Besides this you already commit the current editor outside of  `onDataChange`. So, you have to initiate the editor again inside `onDataChange` to work it out. Check below:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    User user1=null;
    //Check if user not exist in database
    if (dataSnapshot.child(user.getUid()).exists()) {

        user1 = dataSnapshot.child(user.getUid()).getValue(User.class);

        //   user_tbl.removeEventListener(this);
    }

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = settings.edit();
    editor2.putString("username", user1.getUserName());
    editor2.apply();
}
```

Comment: Really great..it works like a charm thanks for solution @Md Asaduzzaman

Answer (score 0):

Make your  SharedPreferences settings as static and you can easily access anywhere between any activity and fragment that will be one of the best way to do it

public static SharedPreference settings  ;

Then use it further and I hope this have helped you.